# How do I create static instances of a class inside that class?

Tags: c#

I have a class Color that holds values for the red, green, and blue channels of a color. The class constructor lets you create a new color by specifying values for the three channels. However, for convenience, I would also like to have some "premade" colors available for the programmer. For example instead of having something like

```
DrawRectangle(new Color(1, 0, 0));
```

you would be able to say

```
DrawRectangle(Color.Red);
```

Where Color.Red is an instance of Color that lives inside the Color class. How can I declare these instances of Color inside the Color class? If there is a name for this type of technique I'd like to know it as I had no idea what search terms to use when I was looking for help online.

Comment: And you're not using System.Drawing.Color because?

Comment: Just an FYI, System.Drawing.Color may already cover what you're looking to create.

Answer (score 8):

use static variables:

```
class Color
{
    public Color(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        //..
    }
    public static readonly Color Red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather comment on BrokenGlass' answer, but I am not allowed, yet.

```
public static readonly Color Red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
```

It would be better to make the field readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the call have a dec like this `public static Color Red = new Color(1,0,0);`